# Find first minimum gradient python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gradient, analysis

I would need to find the first minimum of the `gradient_array` array, then the local minimum that is within the first 50 meters.

```py
gradient_array= np.gradient(moving_avg_RCS)
MLH = min(gradient_array)
```

Attached: plot in which you can see the point of the minimum that it finds. I need the first minimum within 50 meters  [image]

---

EDIT:

```py
sodar_data = pd.read_csv('20141222_sodar-data.csv')    
headers=(sodar_data.columns).tolist()
height_str=headers[1:]    
height=[float(i) for i in height_str]  

gradient_array= np.gradient(moving_avg_RCS) 
MLH = min(gradient_array)
gradient = gradient_array.tolist()
index = gradient.index(MLH)
MLHS_height = height[index]
```

Comment: How do you get the depth meter information? Please provide more information, and edit your post : there's no need to paste the image of your entire array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `np.array` for that :

```
height = np.array(height)  
gradient_array_within_50_meters = gradient_array[height < 50]

min_within_50_meters = gradient_array_within_50_meters.min()
height_min_within_50_meters = height[gradient_array_within_50_meters.argmin()]
```

Comment: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 152 but corresponding boolean dimension is 156

Comment: This means that your `height` array does not have the same length as `moving_avg_RCS`. This is a data concern, you should check your .csv to see what's wrong.